# Add shadow to selected Edges UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I need to create UIView with shadow but I need shadow only on right,left,bottom edge -> No shadow on top edge. Is possibility to do that ? I tried with different offset but I did not achive my goal.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want shadow coming from one edge of the rectangle? So for example, shadow appears from the bottom but not from the top or sides?

Comment: You probably want to use `CALayer` and `.shadowPath` - here's a decent starter blog post: https://nachbaur.com/2010/11/16/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths/  (not mine)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
let yourView = UIView()
yourView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // NEEDS A COLOR TO SHOW SHADOW
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
self.view.addSubview(yourView)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, the best way to overcome the latter problem is to create an @IBDesignable extension of UIView and declare @IBInspectable properties as mentioned below

```
public extension UIView {

    // MARK: - Inspectables

    /**
     Defines the color of the shadow behind the view (defaults to nil).
     */

    @IBInspectable public var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                self.layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        } get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    /**
     Defines the radius of the shadow behind the view.
     */

    @IBInspectable public var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        set(newValue) {
            self.layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        } get {
            return self.layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }

    /**
     Defines the opacity of the shadow behind the view.
     */

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOpacity: Float {
        set(newValue) {
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        } get {
            return self.layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    /**
     Defines the offset of the shadow behind the view.
     */

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        set(newValue) {
            self.layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        } get {
            return self.layer.shadowOffset
        }
    }

}
```

Afterwards, you will be able to find the latter parameters for every UIView (or class that inherits from UIView) in your storyboards.

If you are, however, working programmatically, then you will have to experiment with the `shadowOffset` property until you achieve the desired visual effect.